# "even last" Array javascript exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays

still fairly new to javascript and trying to sharpen my skills.  I need to access all the even indexes of an array and then add them together and finally multiply them by the last number in the array.  So for instance the answer should be 30 for [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Here is what i have at the moment.

```
   function evenLast() {
   a=[0,1,2,3,4,5];
   b=[];
   answer=0;
    for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if((a[i] % 2) === 0) {
        b.push(a[i]);
        answer= eval(b.join('+'));
      } 
    }
}
```

I keep getting uncaught reference errors on all of the variables but am not sure why.  I know my loop should work correctly.  I have tried slicing the last index with (-0) as well but until the rest is working I can't tell if that is quite working.

Comment: I would think you'd want the `eval` to come after the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Don’t use `eval`. What’s wrong with `answer += a[i]`? Also, you should declare your variables.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your errors, but you should have the `eval` after the end of the loop (though `eval` is not a great way to do this).

Ultimately, I'd use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the even indices.

```js
var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5];

var answer = a.reduce(function(s, n, i) {
  return i % 2 ? s : (s + n);
}) * a[a.length-1];

document.body.innerHTML = answer;
```

---

Nicer to reuse named functions IMO.

```js
function sumEven(s, n, i) {
  return i % 2 ? s : (s + n);
}


var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5];

var answer = a.reduce(sumEven) * a[a.length-1];

document.body.innerHTML = answer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
function evenLast() {
   var a=[0,1,2,3,4,5];
   var answer=0;
   for(var i=0; i < a.length; i+=2) answer += a[i]; // sum all even items
   answer *= a[a.length - 1]; // multiply by last item
   // answer is now 30
}
```

Comment: I tried this one and it seems like it should work.  I have an about:blank page open and running the console in chrome.  It keeps throwing undefined or saying uncaught reference error with the variables.  If I declare them outside the function it reads them when I console.log() them but not if they're in the function.  Even when I run console.log(answer) in the function I still get undefined.  Calling the function throws undefined too.  Any ideas why?

Comment: All the variable in the function above are local to the function. So trying to log them outside won't work. But when you add a `console.log(answer);` as the last statement in the function, it should work.

Comment: Yeah it's not working for some reason.  I am copying and pasting what you wrote and have modified it several ways.  Is there some weird feature with chrome console I don't know about maybe?

Comment: Can you paste the modified version here as a comment? I can look into it if you want.

Comment: I actually just got it.  Must have had a missing little something somewhere.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
var arr=[0,1,2,3,4,5],
    sum=0,
    last=arr[arr.length-1]; 

 $.each(arr,function(index,value){   
        if(index%2 == 0)
         sum+=value;
 }); 

alert(sum*last);
```

JsFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/ggb8919a/